# Apache Spark MLlib clustering only runs on one machine although inside cluster (standalone)

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, apache-spark-ml

I want to set up Spark to run different MLlib algorithms on a cluster. For my first test I tried to run K-means clustering with a superhuge dataset on two machines using the simple Spark Standalone Mode. But it seems that only one of the machines is doing any work while the other remains idle.

This is how I set up everything: I downloaded the latest version (spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7) and unpacked it on both machines. Then I copied the dataset into the data/mllib folder. Then I copied the file conf/spark-env.sh.template to conf/spark-env.sh and added the following lines:

```
SPARK_HOME=</path/to/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7>
SPARK_LOCAL_IP=<machine 1 address>/<machine 2 address>
SPARK_MASTER_HOST=<machine 1 address>
```

Then I launched the cluster by executing the following commands on machine 1 (the master) inside the Spark directory:

```
./sbin/start-master.sh
./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://<machine 1 address>:7077
```

And the following line on the slave:

```
./sbin/start-slave.sh spark://<machine 1 address>:7077
```

Then I launched the shell on the master:

```
./bin/spark-shell --master spark://<machine 1 address>:7077
```

Afterwards the WebGUI (http://:8081/) shows me that both workers are alive and all of their cores (80 total) are used. Then I executed the following script inside the spark-shell:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.KMeans
val dataset = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/superhuge_dataset.txt")
val kmeans = new KMeans().setK(2000).setSeed(1L)
val model = kmeans.fit(dataset)
```

But when I observe both machines using **top** while the computation is running only machine 1 (the master) shows me processor usage. One java process uses almost 4800% (the machine has 48 cores) while the other machine (32 cores) does not show any CPU usage at all.

According to the WebGUI and the master-log both machines are connected to the master. When I turn off the (working) slave on machine 1 and run the script again the second slave still remains idle and I get the following warning on the shell: "Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources"

But according to the webgui I have plenty of ressources left on my remaining worker. Did I miss any step in the setup or the script which is required to distribute the computation on both machines? Is there maybe some connectivity issue, e.g. another port apart from 7077 I need to open? Thanks a lot in advance!